# plotly fig object to redis

Tags: python, redis, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a plotly figure object (type: class 'plotly.graph_objs._figure.Figure') and I need to convert it to other data type which can be store and retrieve from redis database.

I am using python. Please help me with any ideas how to convert the type

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you need, from the docs [here](https://plot.ly/python/user-guide/#why-graphobjs):

```py
  get_data(self, flatten=False)
      Returns the JSON for the plot with non-data elements stripped.

      Flattening may increase the utility of the result.

      :param (bool) flatten: {'a': {'b': ''}} --> {'a.b': ''}
      :returns: (dict|list) Depending on (flat|unflat)
```